# Lucene and cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm using Neo4j 2.0 and would to to know if/how I can the following things with Cyhper.

The first is lucene scores. In the docs there are some mentions of 1.x methods to get this with java, but I'm using Cypher with Neo4j 2.0 and the REST API.

The other thing is I would like to add extra words to the index, mainly for plural and some similar things, so that I can put both car and cars in the index for a node with name "car".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Lucene specific configugrations are not exposed in Cypher as of yet, since the index query syntax should be hidden from the Cypher API. In later versions, there is possibly a more comprehensive way to get parameters down to the underlying index provider for the labels. For the time being, please use the Java Index API (1.9.X), and build a server plugin exposing your special lucene configuration enpoint.